# View component of MVC. Should I pre generate HTML tag elements in the Controller for the View?

Tags: model-view-controller, view, struts2

I'am currently creating a MVC Java Web App with Struts2.

One element of my app is searching for some results via form. When the user submits the form an Action gets the necessary values from the database and populates a Map:

```
Map<Integer,List<String>> values = new HashMap<Integer,List<String>>();
```

Which has a list of column values for each row.

By Following this approach I can have  generic JSP for displaying the results of any resultbox:

```
<s:div cssClass='resultContainer'
cssStyle=' min-height: 150px; max-height:%{header}px; overflow: auto; %{display}; '
theme="qxhtml">


<table id='resultTable'>
    <tr id='tableHeader'>
        <s:iterator value="headers">
            <th><s:property /></th>
        </s:iterator>
    </tr>
    <s:iterator value="values">
        <tr class='results'>
            <s:iterator value="value">
                <td><s:property escape="false" /></td>
            </s:iterator>
        </tr>
    </s:iterator>
</table>
```

I feel now that this is a bad approach. Instead I should change the Map to a List of ResultBoxRow objects. Each ResultBox will have its own View Jsp instead of one generic one allowing me to iterate over the objects and output for example:

```
<s:iterator value="value">
<td><s:property name="firstname" /></td>
<td><s:property name="lastname" /></td>
```

etc.

In the case of the table headers I may need to give certain headers individual style properties. I feel these should be defined in the JSP itself rather than get the JSP to reference a value from the controller containing the style for that header.

I think my overall question is how much should the controller control the style/display of elements of the View? I feel it should just generate the individual elements displayed in the  tags but not the values to put in the "style" tag of the row for example. Even if this does sacrifice a simple single JSP to handle every result box.

It would be great to get your opinions.

Answer (score 0):

The controller should have nothing to do with the display mechanism: that's the *point* of MVC, to completely separate the data from its presentation.

You can still DRY up the view layer via custom tags, includes, templates, etc. Styles may be passed as attributes, while the underlying DOM would be created by a single page or template.

It also matters what the *nature* of the attributes you want to pass. If they're *semantic* that could *logically* from from the model or controller that's fine. If they're *purely* presentational, like colors, widths, etc. then it has no business in the model or controller.

Comment: Thanks Dave. You've made things more clear. Therefore do you think my new approach for having a View for each different ResultBox makes sense, as the data for each result box will be created from its own controller? 

I suppose if there are any clear similarities between the Views, these could be represented as sub views within each of the resultbox jsps?

Comment: @user1782673 Without a concrete example I'm not really sure what you're doing, or trying to. I think re-using generic views is great, although I've found actually *doing* so rarely works because there aren't too many things that can be represented generically. Tables are one of the things that *can* be re-used, but I generally use a component for that.

Comment: The above generic JSP is the one I have at the moment. In the future some of the <th> tags may have particular styles when compared to the rest of the <th> tags in the table. I could define these styles/css classes as a variable within my controller for my view to output but I feel this wouldn't follow MVC principles. As a result For this case I would create a separate JSP hard coding the header values for the resultBox giving the styles/css classes a particular <th> may have.

Comment: @user1782673 There are any number of ways to go about that, including passing in an array of header styles, allowing the inclusion of a separate header template, etc. I'd consider using something like Displaytag, though, depending on your actual needs.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look at that. So potentially generating these styles/css classes in the controller might be a correct approach?